# TextView Text Not Updating

Tags: android, textview

```
package com.aviyehuda.test.multithreading;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MultithreadingTest extends Activity {
Button btn;
private Handler myHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
}

public void buttonClicked(View v) {
    myHandler = new Handler();
    MyThread mThread = new MyThread();
    mThread.start();
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            myHandler.post(new NewThreaad(i));
        }
    }
}
class NewThreaad implements Runnable{
    int i;
    public NewThreaad(int n) {
        i=n;
    }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01)).setText("Hello:"+i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
}
```

I have code mentioned above but getting result Hello29 on TextView but i want Hello1,Hello2,hello3.................Hello29 one by one automatically

Please give me hint what I am doing wrong

Comment: Do you want the results all together in one string at the end or do you want each new result to replace the other with a 500 ms delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the 500 ms delay to your for-loop, between posting of messages. I  think you're expecting the messages to execute sequentially one after the other, but they don't, which is the reason you just see the result of the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the main problem is that you're not *appending* you are *overwriting*. Instead of

```
 ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01)).setText("Hello:"+i);
```

do

```
  TextView tv = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01));
  String text = tv.getText().toString();
  tv.setText(text + " Hello:" + i);
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things.

First, after changing the text, you should call [invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) on the TextView to force a refresh.

Second, to do operation on the UI, you should run that in the UI thread. Use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)